# I'm running a css animation within a Jquery script. I want the animation to be completely independent of JS.

Tags: javascript, css, typed.js

I have class='tom' shown below:

```
<div id="typed-strings">
<p>Forget originality.^500 The term is overrated.^500<br> 
<span class='tom'>Ideas aren't original</span>. Ideas are made from stuff.<br>
</p>
</div>
<span id="typed"></span>
```

which has animation property:

```
.tom{
animation-name: highlight;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-delay: 0.5s;
background-color: transparent;
}

@keyframes highlight{
from {background-color: transparent;}
to {background: rgba(199, 220, 101, 0.4);}
}
```

As you can see from this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/harrydry/p4ev1nj2/18/

with an animation delay of 0.5s the animation only starts after the typing effect has stopped.

This means I can't sync the animation with the class="line1" which is causing problems.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Is this what you wanted? https://jsfiddle.net/p4ev1nj2/19/

Comment: update this is the latest attempt.

https://jsfiddle.net/harrydry/5ngvafpz/35/

but it still isn't working on the source code?